# How can I see the history of an ERC1155 token on-chain?

Tags: transactions, erc-721, erc-1155, sendtransaction, history

Let's say I have 10 tokens of a specific token id within an `ERC1155` smart contract.

If I send 1 of those tokens to another address and then this address send it elsewhere, is there a way I can see the transaction history of THAT specific token?

This is possible in `ERC721` because we have a `tokenID` for each minted asset. I don't know if the same case applies for `ERC1155`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to work exactly like ERC721 then it is not possible, the reason you already know is that a single token ID contains multiple tokens. So it is like ERC20 i.e. fungible.

I guess there can be a way to scan the blockchain and filter the data to get this but it would be much lengthy than scanning for an ERC721.